# How to expand chart to match width of container using ngx-charts

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, ngx-charts

I'm trying to use `ngx-charts` to display an `area` chart that spans the full width of my page (it's supposed to match the width of the horizontal line above it). However, it appears that when generating a chart there is some sort of padding inside the `svg`, which I imagine is useful if you have a legend etc but I am not using that, here's what I see:

[image]

See how the actual area chart doesn't expand the full width?

My code:

```
 <ngx-charts-area-chart
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [results]="heatmaps"
    [curve]="curve"
    [showGridLines]="showGridLines"
    [tooltipDisabled]="tooltipDisabled"
    (select)="onSelect($event)">
  </ngx-charts-area-chart>
```

And my config variables in my `component.ts`

```
  curve = d3.curveNatural;
  showGridLines = false;
  tooltipDisabled = true;
  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#3f3f3f']
  };
```

As you can see I am not using the `view` attribute so the chart should expand to the width of the page. I was thinking I could utilize a `viewBox` on the `svg` but not quite sure, any thoughts?

Thanks!